# Vue3: Updating an attribute on an object in an array raises an error "Cannot read property 'el' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to update an object key in an array on vue 3 data:

The code kind of looks like this:

```
<!-- template area -->

            <template v-if="currentComponent === 'join-select-options-vue'">
                <join-select-options-vue
                    v-on:set-option-change="setOptionChangeEvent"
                    v-bind:options="options"
                    v-bind:next-component="nextComponent"
                    v-bind:previous-component="currentComponent"
                >

                </join-select-options-vue>
            </template>

<!-- stuff -->

// script area

export default {
        data() {
            return {
                options: [
                    { label: "one", selected: false },
                    { label: "two", selected: false }
                ],


      // more stuff


      methods: {
            setOptionChangeEvent: function(updatedOption) {

                const index = this.options.findIndex((option) => {
                    return option.label === "one";
                });

                let optionToUpdate = this.options[index]
                optionToUpdate.selected = true  // <--- error here
      }
```

The error raised is:

```
vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:7184 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined
    at patchBlockChildren (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:7184)
    at patchElement (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:7159)
    at processElement (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:6984)
    at patch (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:6901)
    at patchBlockChildren (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:7198)
    at processFragment (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:7259)
    at patch (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:6897)
    at patchUnkeyedChildren (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:7625)
    at patchChildren (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:7575)
    at processFragment (vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js:7278)
```

Am I doing this wrong in the Options API? All examples I'm coming across are for the Composition API.

Update:

The only thing it does not error on update is an empty array. Even if if I update it with the initial objects it gives the same error.

Comment: `method: {` or `methods: {`?

Comment: Where are you calling the method?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim sorry about that. I fixed it in the example. It is `methods` though in the code. Just a copy/paste error on my part as I was trying to simplify the example for SO

Comment: @ftrsk I added the template section to the example. The emit is coming from another component. I have already inspected the data coming in and it is correct. I think it's something with actual setting of the data. In Vue 3 there's a bunch of concepts I'm still not understanding like `ref`, `toRef`, `reactive` but they are all compositions. I haven't stumbled across anything regarding the Options API :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to a `:key` in a for loop that was an object. I was able to find it because many of the other answers on here for that sort of error message ended up fixing the template.

I then incrementally removed templates until the error went way, finally coming across the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
methods: {
    setOptionChangeEvent(updatedOption) {
        this.options = this.options.map((x) => 
            x.label === "one"
                ? { ...x, selected: true }
                : x
        )
    }
// ...
}
```

It's safer to create a new array instead of modifying the existing one (as inefficient it might seem...)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get the same error however.